# Printing via `print()` doesn't print all pages in Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, printing

I'm wondering about using the print option by using JavaScript in Firefox.

I have a page that has a print link:

```
<a href="javascript:print()">print</a>
```

I also have followed the instructions on About Javascript's [print button](http://javascript.about.com/library/blprint.htm) page.

The problem is that when I try to print a page under Firefox, I get a four page PDF preview with missing content:

- The first page is empty,
- The second will start with the content that should be on the third page, and
- The third and fourth pages are empty

I tried using Chrome, and it works as expected.

Any ideas?

Comment: You'll have to quote the markup of the page giving you trouble, ideally first creating a **minimal, self-contained example** demonstrating the problem.

Comment: @ bonny: So someone *guessed* correctly. That doesn't mean you shouldn't ask the question properly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best way to get a consistent printing behaviour is using a print stylesheet. This defines exactly, which content should be printed how, because browsers differ strongly on that matter. Some browsers have problems with certain markup (e.g. floated elements).

You can find a very good article about print stylesheets on **[A List Apart](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/goingtoprint/)** that should be very helpful for you.

Certainly there might be other good articles which are newer but this ALA article is so fundamental that it still is worth reading even though it is 10 years old - which is like stoneage for web-content;)

Comment: This! Media type sensitive CSS documents for the win.

Answer (score 1):

It's all because of Firefox inability to handle different container styles. I use UIkit and fixed the issue by adding the following code to my CSS file:

```
@media print
{   
    .uk-grid {
        display: inline !important
    }
}
```

You might want to set "display: inline !important" for classes you use.